# How do you use strings in a class?

Tags: c++, string, class

Well I've been working on this for awhile but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

int numofstudents = 5;
Student ** StudentList = new Student*[numofstudents];
string tempLname = "smith";
StudentList[0]->SetLname(tempLname);


#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student {

public:
  void SetLname(string lname);
  void returnstuff();

protected:
  string Lname;

};

#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Student::SetLname(string lname) {
  Lname = lname;
}
```

All I want to do is set `Lname` to `smith` but when I run my program it crashes without telling me an error after it runs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you guys I wish I had asked this sooner :p

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is nothing to do with using strings. It is to do with using pointers.

```
Student ** StudentList=new Student*[numofstudents];
```

This allocates an array of Student pointers. It does not allocate an array of Student objects. So, as of this line of code, you have an array of 5 invalid pointers. Which is a problem when you try to access them as if they point to Student objects, here:

```
StudentList[0]->SetLname(tempLname);
```

In order for that line to be valid, `StudentList[0]` first needs to point to a valid `Student` object. You can either Set it to an existing object:

```
Student st;
StudentList[0] = &st;
```

Or you can allocate a new object:

```
StudentList[0] = new Student;
```

Otherwise get rid of the extra level of indirection:

```
Student * StudentList=new Student[numofstudents];
...
StudentList[0].SetLname(tempLname);
```

But why on Earth would you do that? If you need a 1-dimensional dynamic collection of `Student` objects, then use a [sequence container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) from the standard library, such as a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

change `Student ** StudentList=new Student*[numofstudents];` to

```
Student ** StudentList=new Student*[numofstudents];
for(int i = 0; i<numofstudents; i++)
    StudentList[i] = new Student();
```

Answer (score 0):

You created array of pointers to Student but the elements of array were not initialized, so dereference of any element, in particular [0] leads to crash. 
Use "std::vector StudentList(numofstudents);" instead with minor changes in code "StudentList[0].SetLname(tempLname);"